# JSHint W117 inline ignore

Tags: jslint, jshint, grunt-contrib-jshint

JSHint override not being respected.

> [Output]: [L59:C38] W117: 'alert' is not defined.
>
> [Output]:         /*jshint -W117 */alert("failed to load review data..");/*jshint +W117 */

-- Actual line of code:

```
$scope.example.$get(
    function(data){
       $scope.data =  //do something;
    }, function(message){
        /*jshint -W117 */alert("failed..");/*jshint +W117 */
});
```

I use these for other warnings, but W117 seems to be ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
alert("failed.."); //jshint ignore:line
```

Answer (score 6):

Try have them on a seperate line

```
/* jshint -W117 */
alert("failed..");
/* jshint +W117 */
```

Another option to disable the warning is to add this at the top of the file

```
/* global alert */
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a `.jshintrc` file with this content:

```
{
  "globals": {
    "alert": false
  }
}
```

The [globals](http://jshint.com/docs/options/#globals) configuration option says that this variable is a global defined elsewhere, and the `false` value says that it shouldn't be redefined.